# Importing XML-Files from a huge zip-folder to one excel-sheet

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a huge zip-folder containing over 50.000 xml-files. Each XML-file contains one to three rows with 31 columns of data. I want to make a code in VBA that automatically imports all this files into one big matrix in excel containing all these data. I have struggled with these for days, please, do any one of know where to start? I'm a new beginner at coding in VBA.

Comment: You want to open each xml file and pull all the data, then go to the next one and pull all the data in below where the previous one ended? What VBA do you have already?

Answer (score 0):

1. Unzip the files.
2. Create a VBA loop using the `Dir` function to loop through all the XML files
3. Import the data as XML file. See this post: [How to read XML attributes using VBA to Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117667/how-to-read-xml-attributes-using-vba-to-excel)