# VBA XML read node, if attribute = 1, read other attributes in that node. Do the same for all nodes

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am trying to write a Excel VBA script to selectively take information from a xml file and make a table with that information.

There is thousands of node all name defect, and in each defect are attributes.
I want to use an attribute in each defect to filter some undesired defects, and of the desired defects list all the other attributes in the nodes named defect.

Please see below for more information. nextSibling can not be used.

XML structure:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<CDXML>
<DATA><FaceInformation><Defects>
<Defect>
    <Black Type="Integer" Value="1"/>
    <Dots Type="Integer" Value="21"/>
    <Height Type="Integer" Value="1"/>
</Defect>
<Defect>
    <Black Type="Integer" Value="0"/>
    <Dots Type="Integer" Value="22"/>
    <Height Type="Integer" Value="2"/>
</Defect>
<Defect>
    <Black Type="Integer" Value="1"/>
    <Dots Type="Integer" Value="23"/>
    <Height Type="Integer" Value="3"/>
</Defect>
</Defects></FaceInformation></DATA>
```

Desired output:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Black    Dots     Height
1        21       1
1        22       3
```

VBA:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
xmlDoc.async = False
Dim n, m As IXMLDOMNode
Dim j As Integer

XMLFileName = C:\1.xml
xmlDoc.Load (XMLFileName)

'This goes through all the attributes with the name Black,
'this is okay since Black only appear once in each node called defect.
For Each n In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Defects/Defect/Black")
    'Read value of the Black attribute
    Black = n.Attributes.getNamedItem("Value").Text
    If Black <> "0" Then 'Print if 1
        Cells(j + 3, 2) = Black
        'I can not use nextSibling because the order of defects is not always the same
        For Each m In n.SelectNodes("DefectClass")
            Dots = m.Attributes.getNamedItem("Value").Text
            'I have no idea what to do from this point
            Cells(i + 3, 3) = Dots
        Next
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: To me appears some typo errors such as `XMLFileName = C:\1.xml
` should be within quotes `"XMLFileName = C:\1.xml
"`. Further `Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30` gives compiler error on my excel 2007 system. If I make it `DOMDocument60` it is acceptable. I looked into stack overflow old posts and found one by @David Zemens related and interesting.<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117667/how-to-read-xml-attributes-using-vba-to-excel/19118292#19118292> Taking clues from his program , I hope you will be able to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the full extent of the `XMLDOM` features to achieve your task. I'm not sure which library you're using, but I've used `Microsoft XML, v6.0`.

1. make sure your `XML` is correct. I think it might be missing a `</CDXML>` closing tag.
2. make sure your filename is a string when using `xmlDoc.Load(filename)`.
3. I wonder if your phraseology is causing you confusion. The `<Defect>` element has no attributes. It has three child elements that themselves have attributes - and it is these attributes that you are after.
4. the `SelectNodes()` function passes a query string which can include an attribute filter, like this: `"//Black[@Value!=""0""]"`. You can use this function to acquire your target elements.
5. if you are reluctant to loop through the siblings, then you can derive the parent of your node and then select your target children nodes by name. Thankfully the `XMLDOM` model will return `Nothing` rather than an error if no nodes are found and, obviously, it does not worry about the order the nodes are in, they just have to be children of the parent. So you can simply check that all of your attributes are not `Nothing` and then write the values to your excel sheet.

So your code could look something like this:

```
Dim xmlFileName As String
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim query As String
Dim black As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim dots As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim height As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim rng As Range

Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
xmlDoc.async = False

xmlFileName = "C:\1.xml"
query = "//Black[@Value!=""0""]"

xmlDoc.Load (xmlFileName)
Set nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(query)

If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(, 3)
    rng.Value = Array("Black", "Dots", "Height")
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1)

    For Each node In nodeList
        Set black = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Value")
        Set dots = node.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("Dots").Attributes.getNamedItem("Value")
        Set height = node.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("Height").Attributes.getNamedItem("Value")

        If Not black Is Nothing And Not dots Is Nothing And Not height Is Nothing Then
            rng.Value = Array(black.Text, dots.Text, height.Text)
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "No elements found using the query: " & query
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your patients, there are many errors in the information I gave.

I have learned a lot more from this.